# Facebook Login via PHP SDK, then use JS SDK

Tags: javascript, php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I have developed an application where users login via facebook (PHP SDK); now I would like to add JS SDK too, because I want to implement a generic friend selector (http://facebook-friend-selector.codersgrave.com/) that works with JS SDK. I have two questions about:

1) Can mixing the two SDK lead to problems?

2) I added the JS SDK code as explained in the documentation and tried a simple request

```
FB.api('/me/friends', function(response) {
   alert(JSON.stringify(response));
});
```

but I get an error (unknown error); I also tried a dialog box

```
FB.ui({
  method: 'feed',
  link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/dialogs/',
  caption: 'An example caption',
}, function(response){});
```

but the box appears and suddenly disappears. I think the issue is related to the authentication...I guess, since my users are authenticated via PHP, that I need to pass the access token to JS, but how? This question [Passing the Facebook Authorization Token from PHP to Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5540520/passing-the-facebook-authorization-token-from-php-to-javascript) seems to be exactly what I need but I don't understand the answer: it says to store the token in a cookie, but how can JS know about it, which name the cookie should have?
Finally, if I do something like

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    alert('connected');
    var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
    var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
  }
 });
```

I actually get a "connected" alert, that means that JS knows that the user is logged in, even if the login was via PHP, so where is the problem?

Comment: hahaha great mind think alike? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20785993/given-url-is-not-permitted-by-app-setting-with-js-sdk-but-not-with-loginurl-fr. please open some javascript console before loading the page (firebug, chrome default console, IE default console), and see if you are getting any log message about a problem with your domain. tell me what you see. P.S still I can't believe how similar are our situations.

Comment: Yes, exactly same situation :) But in my case, I don't get any error!
If I try to log the answer to the ajax calls 
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed and  https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends both are executed in 0ms (according to firefox) and there is no answer.

Comment: Sorry I meant I don't get any specific error like in your case, the debug alert says "unknown error" as error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. My code contained two stupid mistakes, this is the correct code:

```
function test(){
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
            var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;

            FB.api('/me/friends', function(response) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(response));
            });
        }
    });
}

<a href="" onclick="test();return false;">Test</a>
```

In the first version the call to the friends method was outside the getLoginStatus method, so it was called before setting the variable accesToken, furthermore, I haven't the "return false" statement after the test() call.