# "Given URL is not permitted by app setting" with JS SDK but not with LoginURL from server side?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using Facebook API on a MVC 4 project. By far I've used C# Facebook SDK on the server side, and generated a login url to the client.

I'm running my website on localhost (connecting through my internal ip: 192.168.0...) so I've set the app setting (on facebook side) to accept this ip as my domain.

Notice I'm using http, but not with standard port 80. I've set facebook app setting to accept my ip with this port. For example: `http://192.168.0.2:8080`

By far everything worked fine. I manage to connect to facebook with the generated login url.

Then I wanted to add a friend-selector into my site, so I've decided to use javascript sdk on the client side, as there many ready-to-go libraries.

But when I've used the javascript sdk, facebook kept throw me errors for my domain.

```
  Given URL is not permitted by the application configuration.:
  One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.
  It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL,
  or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.
```

I've used facebook snippet for initializing the sdk. (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/)

And I've set the same AppId I'm using on the server side.

I've opened the page with Firefox and run with firebug another facebook snippet. 
(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/)

This snippet suppose to open a login window. But instead it just opens a window with the above error.

Here's the login script, as found in facebook tutorials:

```
   FB.login(function(response) {
     if (response.authResponse) {
       console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
       FB.api('/me', function(response) {
         console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
       });
     } else {
       console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
     }
   });
```

And here's the initializing script, also from facebook tutorials.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    // init the FB JS SDK
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'SAME APP ID I AM USING ON SERVER SIDE',                        // App ID from the app dashboard
      status     : true,                                 // Check Facebook Login status
      xfbml      : true                                  // Look for social plugins on the page
    });

    // Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here
  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(){
     // If we've already installed the SDK, we're done
     if (document.getElementById('facebook-jssdk')) {return;}

     // Get the first script element, which we'll use to find the parent node
     var firstScriptElement = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];

     // Create a new script element and set its id
     var facebookJS = document.createElement('script'); 
     facebookJS.id = 'facebook-jssdk';

     // Set the new script's source to the source of the Facebook JS SDK
     facebookJS.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';

     // Insert the Facebook JS SDK into the DOM
     firstScriptElement.parentNode.insertBefore(facebookJS, firstScriptElement);
   }());
</script>
```